# using nested printf statements giving strange output

Tags: c, printf

I recently came across this code and I'm unable to understand how it works

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(){
    printf("Line 1\n",
    printf("Line 2\n",
    printf("Line 3\n",
    printf("Line 4\n",
    0))));
return 0;
}
```

It is giving the following output:

```
Line 4
Line 3
Line 2
Line 1
```

Comment: What's wrong with it? The inner most call is resolved first.

Comment: there is no format specifier, what is the meaning of writing another printf or 0 in the above program after the content of ""

Comment: Let me guess... written by a Lisp programmer.

Comment: Its going to wait to see what kind of expression may be evaluated with the call to printf and same with all of them. So the last one is evaluated first, its sent back, then the third one, then the second and the first, etc. These are just function calls, nothing more complicated

Comment: On top of what I said, try evaluating them one by one, without any format specifiers. What you get in `return` is the same thing happening when you nest these function calls. At the end of the day, it is still a step by step process. Just saw the answer by MByD, he/she explains it well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`printf`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/) is used to print a formatted line. For example, to print an integer, you call:

```
printf( "%d", 1 );
```

What you did, is call it with the return value of the nested `print` as argument, which means that it first need to evaluate the nested call. Your call is similar to:

```
int temp;
temp = printf("Line 4\n", 0);
temp = printf("Line 3\n", temp);
temp = printf("Line 2\n", temp);
temp = printf("Line 1\n", temp);
```

Also, note that since you have no format specifiers in the format string, there is no meaning to the second argument, and if your compiler is nice enough it will even warn you about that.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't strange at all.
Expressions are evaluated (executed) from within to outside, just like mathematical expressions.

So put it simple terms: **the expression with the most parentheses around it is evaluated / executed first**.

Simplified it is:

```
printf("1", printf("2", printf("3", printf("4"))));
```

Comment: `the expression with the most parentheses around it is evaluated / executed first.` may be misleading as its not entirely true. Or is it? What if you have an expression with a crap load of operations requiring a crap load of parens and its in the first printf?

Answer (score 3):

You need to evaluate the parameter of a function before actually calling it. So the most inner print is called first.